# setDate to the date whose day is zero that is sunday

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am working on date related reports so in my project as i required to set day to zero (sunday)
Example today is 6 Dec 2012 (Day is Thursday four(4)) i want set it to last weeks sunday that is 25 nov 2012 (Day is Sunday zero(0))

Comment: and what have you tried? why didn't it work?

Comment: You can use `getDay()` to get the current day number, and `getDate()` to get the current date. The use a bit of arithmetic and `setDate()` to set the date to the right date. The rest is up to you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly what you need..

```
    function getLastSunday(leWildDate) {
        var res = new Date();
        res.setDate(leWildDate.getDate() - leWildDate.getDay());
        return res;
    }

    alert(getLastSunday(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var dow = d.getDay();
d.setDate( d.getDate() - dow);
console.log(d);
```